# How to get related model using select on curent query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try to get related model using select in current query, but related model returned `null` value. What's wrong?

Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.1, Postgres 11, NGINX, Laravel 5.7

Query:

```
public function datesFind(Request $request)
{

    $games = Game::where('date_time_start', '<=', $request->get('date'))->where('date_time_end', '>=', $request->get('date'))
            ->where('sport_id', $request->get('sport_id'))->with('gameLevel')->get(['id', 'name', 'sport_id', 'date_time_start', 'date_time_end']);
    return $games;
}
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 135,
        "name": "Новая игра",
        "sport_id": 3,
        "date_time_start": "2019-01-25 00:00:00",
        "date_time_end": "2019-02-25 00:00:00",
        "game_level": null
    },

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to include the foreign key in the field list to load the relation...

Change:

```
$games = Game::where('date_time_start', '<=', $request->get('date'))
              ->where('date_time_end', '>=', $request->get('date'))
              ->where('sport_id', $request->get('sport_id'))
              ->with('gameLevel')
              ->get([
                  'id',
                  'name',
                  'sport_id',
                  'date_time_start',
                  'date_time_end'
              ]);
```

To:

```
$games = Game::where('date_time_start', '<=', $request->get('date'))
              ->where('date_time_end', '>=', $request->get('date'))
              ->where('sport_id', $request->get('sport_id'))
              ->with('gameLevel')
              ->get([
                  'id',
                  'name',
                  'sport_id',
                  'date_time_start',
                  'date_time_end',
                  'game_level_id' // or replace with your foreign key col name...
              ]);
```